# Python FuncAnimation is not updating the frame when I am trying to update 4 plots in a subplot

Tags: python, animation

I am a newbie and trying to get the basics of Python right. I am trying to create an animation with 4 plots using matplotlib.pyplot.subplots. Each plot has same mean but different standard deviation. Here's my code:

import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mlp
import matplotlib.animation as animation

## Test data

```
n = 100
mn = 0
stdv = [1,2,3,4]
x = [np.random.normal(loc= mn, scale = stdv[0], size = n ),
     np.random.normal(loc= mn, scale = stdv[1], size = n ),
     np.random.normal(loc= mn, scale = stdv[2], size = n ),
     np.random.normal(loc= mn, scale = stdv[3], size = n )]
```

## Animation update function

```
def  anim_norm(i):
    if (i == n):
        b.event_source.stop()
    plt.cla()
    ax = [ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4]
    for k in range((len(ax)+1)):
        ax[k].set_title('S.D. = {}, n = {}'.format(stdv[k],i))
        ax[k].set_xlabel('Value')
        ax[k].set_ylabel('Frequency')
        ax[k].hist(x[k][:i])
```

## Running the animation

```
fig,((ax1,ax2),(ax3,ax4)) = plt.subplots(2,2, sharex = True)
b = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,anim_norm, interval = 300)
```

All I see is the plots with xlabel, ylabel, and title and the first frame. I would appreciate any guidance. Also, do I need to increment (i - the frame count) or FuncAnimation does it automatically?

Thank you!

[image]